# Angular.js filter not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-routing

I'm trying to filter based on my $routeParams but must be doing something wrong.

My controller:

```
app.controller('servicesDetail', function ($scope, HC, $resource, $routeParams) { 

HC.API.query(function (results) {
    $scope.services = results;
});

$scope.json={};
json._id=$routeParams.id;

});
```

My HTML/Template:

```
<div class="services" ng-repeat="service in services | filter: json">
        <article class="service group">
       <a href="/services/{{service.name }}"><h3><pre>{{service.name }}</pre> </h3></a> 
       <p>{{service.name}}</p>
       <a href="/services/{{service.name}}">more</a>
       </article>

    </div>
```

My JSON:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53bc3733b7bbbf77208dec65"), "name" : "this is from the client", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53bc37abb7bbbf77208dec66"), "name" : "new", "__v" : 0 }
```

I'm basically just trying to filter a page from a full list to a details page and use the $routeParams to filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.controller('servicesDetail', function ($scope, HC, $resource, $routeParams) { 

HC.API.query(function (results) {
    $scope.services = results;
});

$scope.json={};
//don't forget about $scope
$scope.json._id=$routeParams.id;

});
```

Comment: Thank you! beginners mistake.